# Google Protocol Buffers - Fixed size buffer?

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Using Google Protocol Buffers, can I set a maximum size for all messages I encode?

if I know that what I encode is never larger than X bytes, then Google Protobuffs would always produce a buffer of size Y, and if I give it a smaller amount of data, pad it to size Y?

Answer (score 5):

The wire format for protocol buffers wouldn't make this trivial; I'm not *aware* of something to do this, but one option would be to serialize it into a buffer with *your own* length header and pad with extra data as needed.

You need to add a length prefix because this is not added by default, and otherwise it would be reading garbage at the end of your buffer. Even trailing 0s would not be legal (it would be looking for a field number).

I can't comment on the C++ or Jon's C# version, but for *my* C# version (protobuf-net), you should be able to do something like (untested):

```
using(var  ms = new MemoryStream(fixedLength)) {
     ms.SetLength(fixedLength);
     Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, obj);
     if(ms.Length > fixedLength) { /* boom */ }
     byte[] arr = ms.ToArray(); // use this
}
```

This should deserialize fine if also using `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix`.

---

Re the questions (comments); `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` is a *protobuf-net*-specific method; there *may* be something in the C++ version, but it is pretty simple. The easiest way to implement this *from scratch* is:

- assume we will leave a fixed-length (4 byte) header to indicate how much actual data we have
- skip 4 bytes (or write 00-00-00-00)
- *now* serialize to the rest of the buffer
- find how many bytes you just wrote
- write that value back at the start of the buffer

in reverse, obviously:

- read 4 bytes and interpret as an int
- deserialize that much as data

It is a *little* bit more complex in protobuf-net, as it offers a few more options (how the int should be encoded, and whether or not to wrap this so that the *entire thing* can still be treated as a 100% value protobuf stream - in particular I *suspect* I've just described the behaviour if I asked `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` to use fixed-width encoding and "field 0").

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc, always helpful.
Can you explain in more detail what SerializeWithLengthPrefix actually does?

Thanks again!

Comment: One more thing , I am deserializing with C++ version of Protocol Buffers.... does DeserializeWithLengthPrefix exist in some form in the C++ version??

Comment: @MarcGravell Could you expand your exampel please to show loop to write say 200 obj to me please. I am  not sure how ms position gets moved forward. I very much want to write fixed length records

Comment: If one does go down this route, it is indeed worth defining the endianness one is using for the 4-byte header. If one just uses the 4 bytes to represent a platform-native integer, that might be severely disappointing to someone trying to read the data if their platform stores bytes the other way round!